# newcommand in newcommand, value of variable as parameter

Tags: macros, parameters, variable

I have created a command which creates another command.
The parameter of the first command is a variable which is used in the second command.
I would like the second command returns the value of the variable at the creation of the command.

```
\newcommand\testcom[2]{
    \texttt{newcommand #1 : #2}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{#2}
}

\def \test{1} % set 1 to variable 'test'
\testcom{foofoo}{\test} % create command 'foofoo' and display "newcommand foofoo:1" 

\def \test{2} % set 2 to variable 'test'
\testcom{barfoo}{\test} % create command 'barfoo' and display "newcommand barfoo:2"

\def \test{3} % set 3 to variable 'test'

\foofoo % display '3', excepted '1'

\barfoo % display '3', excepted '2'

\barfoo % display '3', excepted '2'
```

I understand the command `\testcom{barfoo}{\test}` execute `\newcommand\barfoo{\test}` but I has excepted `\newcommand\barfoo{3}`.

Next, I have modified the command to set an intermediate variable with `\edef`.

```
\newcommand\testcom[2]{
    \texttt{newcommand #1 : #2}
    \expandafter\edef\csname test@#1 \endcsname{#2}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\csname test@#1 \endcsname}
}
```

Now, it creates a variable `\test@barfoo` with the value `2` and the command `\barfoo` returns this variable.

I would like know if a smartest method exists. In my context, the second `newcommand` is more complex and `\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{#2}` is not sufficient to replace the `newcommand`.

Comment: if the argument is `\test` defined to be  3 you want to define your command to 3,  but what do you want if the argument is not expandable `\sqrt[2]{4}` for example?

Comment: The `\def`, `\edef`, etc. are always sufficient to replace `\newcommand` because `\newcommand` is nothing more than `\def`. `\newcommand` is only a macro with more obscure syntax without possibility to declare separated parameters and with checking if the defined control sequence is unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both `\foofoo` and `\barfoo` are just defined to be `\test`, they will change their output if you change `\test` (as you've demonstrated). Also, there's no need to create an intermediate `\test@<cmd>`. You can just expand the argument using `\edef`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\testcom[2]{%
  \texttt{newcommand #1 : #2}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\def\test{1} % set 1 to variable 'test'
\testcom{foofoo}{\test} % create command 'foofoo' and display "newcommand foofoo:1" 

\def\test{2} % set 2 to variable 'test'
\testcom{barfoo}{\test} % create command 'barfoo' and display "newcommand barfoo:2"

\def\test{3} % set 3 to variable 'test'

\ttfamily
\string\foofoo: \foofoo % display '1', excepted '1'

\string\barfoo: \barfoo % display '2', excepted '2'

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ulrich Diez tends to increase confusion of beginners by mentioning too many subtle details at once.Despite this things might be clearer by mentioning that Werner's approach with `\edef` is focused on obtaining the "total expansion" of `\test` as definition-text of the macro to be defined via `\testcom` while U's approach is focused on "toplevel expansion" only. I.e., U's  approach just expands `\test` and from the resulting tokens defines the macro while with Werner's approach expandable tokens coming from expanding (expandable tokens coming from expanding [etc]) `\test` get expanded also.

Answer (score 4):

As you did not yet answer the question in David Carlisle's comment I assume that as `\testcom`'s second argument you **always** provide a **single expandable token** (an argumentless macro serving as "variable") and you always wish a macro, whose name is provided in `\testcom`'s first argument, to be defined from the **toplevel-expansion** of that token:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\testcom[2]{%
  \texttt{newcommand #1 : \detokenize\expandafter{#2}}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\def \test{1} % set 1 to variable 'test'
\testcom{foofoo}{\test} % create command 'foofoo' and display "newcommand foofoo : 1" 

\def \test{2} % set 2 to variable 'test'
\testcom{barfoo}{\test} % create command 'barfoo' and display "newcommand barfoo : 2"

\def\woozle{X}%
\def \test{\woozle}
\testcom{barbar}{\test} % create command 'barbar' and display "newcommand barbar : \woozle"

\def \test{3} % set 3 to variable 'test'

\ttfamily

\string\foofoo=\meaning\foofoo % display '1', excepted '1'

\string\barfoo=\meaning\barfoo % display '2', excepted '2'

\string\barbar=\meaning\barbar % display '\woozle', excepted '\woozle'
\end{document}
```

[image]